# Django loop variable as key

Tags: python, django

i am new to django and tried to use the variable of an loop as a key for another object:

this is my views.py

```
...
files = Files.objects.filter(dataset__id = instance.dataset.id)
context = {'files': files, 'range': range(files.count())}
return render_to_response("test.html", context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my test.html looks like this:

```
{% for i in range %}
<img title="{{i}}" src="{{files.i.data_files.url}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

if i use `files.0.data_files.url` (or 1,2,3..) instead of `files.i.` it works, but i want to give out all images and also need the position of the image.

can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

the thing you're probably looking for is a magic variable `{{ forloop.counter }}` (or `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` if you want to use zero-based index) available inside `{% for %}` loop:

```
{% for file in files %}
   <img title="{{ forloop.counter }}" src="{{file.data_files.url}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if i use this, could it be possible that the counter is on e.g. 3 but it takes the 6th file?

Comment: tbh: I didnt fully understand your question, but maybe if you can add your models into the question I could get the idea what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: i mean i have an file object like `files = {0:{...}, 1:{..}, ...}` and wanted to know, if the loop is always sorted or could it possible that that an object from the end is called first in the loop? in this case the counter and the index wouldnt be the same

Comment: and also if i set `files = {2:{..}, 0:{..}, 1:{..}, ..}`, would it then also agree with the counter?

Comment: The code you wrote in your last two comments looks like `files` is a dictionary, but I can see in your **views.py** that it's a `QuerySet` (which is basically a list). So... you didnt explain it, you make it even more confusing. Just put your **models.py** into your question pls!